# SSIS package works in Visual Studio, but fails a sql Agent

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, agent

I have a ssis package that runs perfectly fine in development but when it is deployed to sql agent it fails. Basically the package does is open up an excel file and read. I try switching to 64 bit false but still no good. Sql agent fail on this line adp.Fill(dsXLS). It works before that line. Any thoughts?

Oh this has nothing to do with security. I use a proxy account to run this job and able to copy and move files.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
                "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

        StringBuilder stbQuery = new StringBuilder();
        stbQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]");
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(stbQuery.ToString(), con);


       DataSet dsXLS = new DataSet();

       adp.Fill(dsXLS); //****Fails on this line****`
```

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: It is vague. It says "exception has thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: Are development and prod different servers? Is the ACE driver installed on this server? Maybe you should run your script on a platform that gives you better errors.

Comment: I tested running the package in VS inside production server and it runs. I only failed when it is running in SQL agent in the same production server. It is not an issue with a ACE driver. It is something do with SQL agent.

Comment: This is not a real solution, but I found a fix. I make the above script an EXE and execute in the process and everything works. This must have something to do with sql agent handling the script inside the package. With the same script turned into EXE it runs. Strange